# Citing draft papers

Tags: citations, ethics

I'm working on a project where I've come across a couple relevant papers that are marked as "preliminary drafts" and/or with a request not to cite them because they are preliminary.

Should I cite the most similar, published work, ask the authors for their preference as close to publication as possible, or take a different route?

Comment: The answer to this question depends upon the specific journal you are submitting to and the authors' preference. For example, the Journal of Applied has a specific policy described [here](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/hub/journal/13652664/about/author-guidelines).